# Performance test HTML + JavaScript

Tags: jsperf

On testing different [methods for preventing default event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8614438/1366033), I made the [comment that neither would meaningfully impact performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614438/preventdefault-inside-onclick-attribute-of-a-tag#comment68560600_8614549), and I'd like to back that up with cold, hard data.

Two options under consideration are:

Use an **Attribute**:

```
 <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/8614438/1366033" 
    onclick="event.preventDefault()" target="_blank">onclick attribute</a>
```

Use an **Event Handler**:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/8614438/1366033" target="_blank" >jQuery handler</a>
<script>
    $("body").on("click", "a", function(e) { e.preventDefault() });
</script>
```

[Demo in jsFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8614438/1366033)

I wanted to use [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/) to run through the two test cases.  However, the test cases differ in the the HTML setup as well as the execution of JavaScript.

Is there a way to include different HTML in the jsPerf runner?

[image: JS Perf Test Cases]

Comment: Even though it's technically a web app, you probably want to ask this at [so]. I see over 50 questions tagged [`jsperf`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsperf), and many of them seem of a similar bent.